# How to deal with Node error 'Unhandled promise rejection' so that page gets loaded anyway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm creating a Next.js app served by a Node (Express) server which pulls in data through requests to an API. I keep my request endpoints in a separate `api` file:

```
const apiBase = 'http://www.example.com'

export default {
    news: apiBase + '/news/'
    // other endpoints
}
```

Then I do my requests in `getInitialProps`, and do conditional rendering based on whether the request gives an error or not:

```
static async getInitialProps( { query: { slug } } ) {
    const news = await asyncReq( api.news + slug )
    return { news, error: news.status }
}

render() {
    return this.props.error ? <Error /> : <News />
}
```

`asyncReq` is a helper function that looks like this:

```
export const asyncReq = endpoint => {
    return 
        fetch( endpoint )
        .then( res => { return res.ok ? res.json() : res } )
}
```

This all works fine both when the request is successful and when I get `404` or `500` errors. But suppose I intentionally use a wrong endpoint:

```
const apiBase = 'http://www.example.com'

export default {
    news: wrongApiBase + '/news/'
    // other endpoints
}
```

In this case, Node gives me the following error because `wrongApiBase` is undefined:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 498)
```

which is what it should do, but the error causes the page to never get loaded. What am I supposed to do to handle the error? My idea was to chain a `catch` statement to `asyncReq`, but I'm not sure what I should return from it that I can then use in `getInitialProps`. I tried returning `false` but nothing changes, the page just doesn't load.

```
export const asyncReq = endpoint => {
    return 
        fetch( endpoint )
        .then( res => { return res.ok ? res.json() : res } )
        .catch( err => { // What should I return here? )
}
```

**+++ UPDATE +++**

As it turns out, there was an issue with the error I was producing. Like I said, I was using a wrong variable name (`wrongBaseApi`) to trigger an error, which caused Node to never serve the page. In hindsight, it makes sense, as it's an error with Node code and not with the incoming request.

By using the right variable but assigning it a wrong value (an actually wrong API base, such as `http://dahfjkdahfds.com`, which is a not a Node error but an error with the request), I was able to make the solution of using a try/catch block offered by @iKoala and @DEVCNN work. So my code became:

```
static async getInitialProps( { query: { slug } } ) {
    const news = await asyncReq( api.news + slug )
    return { news }
}

render() {
    // this.props.news.data
    // this.props.news.error
}
```

and

```
export async function asyncReq( endpoint ) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch( endpoint )
        return { 
            data: res.ok ? await res.json().then( val => { return val } ) : null,
            error: res.ok ? false : res.status
        } 
    } catch( error ) {
        return { error } 
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can just use `try catch` in `getInitialProps` and return `{error: true}`

Comment: always catch the errors on the function at the bottom of the stack. It will catch all the errors. To be more specific in recognizing and handling errors, you can catch error of all the functions with a try catch on every function.

Comment: @DEVCNN I'm not sure I understand what you mean exactly—not a Javascript expert here, sorry. Could you please provide a quick example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to handle the error thrown from asyncReq:

```
static async getInitialProps( { query: { slug } } ) {
  try {
    const news = await asyncReq( api.news + slug )
    return { news, error: news.status }
  } catch (err) {
    // any error, including http error 40x and 50x
    return { news: null, error: err };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working for me—the error just blocks everything and I never really seem to get to getInitialProps. I guess I'll try moving the try/catch block inside asyncReq

Comment: you can try to use `console.log` or `console.error` to log the err object thrown in the catch block, it will show you the error details. Also, there are two version of `asyncReq` in your question, my  suggested answer only work with the first version (no .catch block). If you are using the 2nd version of `asyncReq`, the answer should be different and don't forget to print the error object in the .catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good approach but we can achieve by adding an event listener on the root node

```
 window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', rj => {
      this.setState({hasError: true})
    })
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's NodeJS, I would use `process.on()` (instead of `window.addEventListener()`) with the `unhandledRejection` event:

```js
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
    console.log(`Unhandled rejection (promise: ${promise}, reason: ${err})`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your getInitialProps calls asyncReq which in turn calls throwError method. Now if throwError method throws an error, you can catch it with the catch block in getInitialProps. So you should always put a catch block in the function that starts the function chain. To diagnose errors better, you should put the catch block in each function. But as a general rule, catch block in the first function that you call is a must.

```
getInitialProps = async function( { query: { slug } } ) {
try{
const news = await asyncReq( 'http://localhost:3000/' + slug )
return { news, error: news.status }
}
catch(err){
console.log('err:', err);
}
}

const throwError = () => {
throw 'New Error'
}

const asyncReq = endpoint => {
throwError();
return 
    fetch( endpoint )
    .then( res => { return res.ok ? res.json() : res } )
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working for me—the error just blocks everything and I never really seem to get to getInitialProps. I guess I'll try moving the try/catch block inside asyncReq

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you want to handle errors from the fetch call only. Is getInitialProps the method that gets called first? I see that you are not calling render anywhere. Do you see the error being logged?

Comment: Also you need to call your page renderer method in the catch block, if you want it to load anyway.

Comment: I think I got it (see updated question). I chose iKoala's answer because he did answer first, but thank you for your help!